# Can't use jquery.after in dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I open dialog when `mybutton` is clicked.

```
$(".mybutton").bind("click", function(){
    var $sprintEditContent = $("<div></div>");
    var url = Issue.constants.CONTEXT + "project/" + "/xxx/edit";
    $sprintEditContent.load(url, function(){
        $sprintEditContent.dialog({
            title : 'xxx',
            width : 650,
            height : 'auto',
            modal : true,
            open : function() {
            }
            });
     });
});
```

In the dialog i load a new html page.
There is some `javascripts` in this page

```
for (var s in sprints){
    var sprint = sprints[s];
            html = ...<tr> <td> --sprint..
        $('#sprintsTable tr:last').after(html);
    }
```

When the dialog is first opened ,the html is showed in the dialog.
but if i close it and reopen it, i can see the html of the table is changed`( $('#sprintsTable').html() is changed)`, but the content can't be seen in the dialog.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: use `insertAfter()` may be better?

Comment: there is anonymous open function why is that?

Comment: i change after to insertAfter and remove the anonymous function,it still does work.

Comment: Can you give us a demo or fiddle?

Comment: can you please create a fiddle for better understanding. For now what i feel is you should declare var html before for loop and use += to append the for loop's content.